# Excel Window Top search box. How to hide?

Tags: microsoft-excel

The search results returned by trying to search for this question on google, etc. are very ambiguous. I need to ask an actual person on here.

First the screenshot:

[image: image1]

**I often Drag the window by clicking on this area and** this Search Box doesn't allow me to accomplish Dragging. It's.. in the way.

Where do I go to Hide it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Where do I go to hide the Search Box?

> To remove the Microsoft search box in the top bar of your Excel
>   window:
>
> - In the upper left hand corner of your Excel window, click File
> - Scroll all the way down to the bottom of the screen that opens
> - In the bottom left, click Options
> - In the new screen that opens click on General on the left side (you may notice that General is already selected)
> - On the right side of the screen, under User Interface Options, click the checkbox next to ‘Collapse the Microsoft Search box by
>     default’
> - Click OK
>
> [image]

Source [How to Get Rid of Search Box in Top Bar of Excel - Logically Tech](https://www.logicallytech.com/blog/how-to-get-rid-of-search-box-in-top-bar-of-excel/)

Answer (score 2):

Go to File→Options→General

and click the Collapse the Microsoft Search box by Default

[image]

Comment: Collapse... No wondering my eyes skipped right over it countless times. Thank you!